# How to perform Batch Geocoding on google or some other geocoding service provider?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

How to perform Batch Geocoding on google or some other Geocoding service provider. I dont want batch address processing where the application uses a JavaScript to break the address batch into single address in a loop and perform geocoding like the sample provider here (http://onemarco.com/2007/06/03/geocoding-with-the-google-maps-api/). I want to perform a batch geocoding where I can submit a bulk address in the from of file or text diretly to the service provider and get a suitable response.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Probably BatchGeo.com will help you out, it's based on the Google Maps API but you can choose to use Yahoo's geocoding service too. BatchGeo does a very decent job. Otherwise there are quite a few (commercial) API based solutions like http://maplarge.com/geocoder

Check out the wikipedia page on geocoding, it has a pretty comprehensive list.

Answer (score 0):

While there are few batch geo  processes out there, they are very different.
Some use old interpolations and are off by 30-300 feet on average. That is significant in an urban environment. 
It is not clear from the question if you are referring to API or just an application.
For application I would recommend [CSV2Geodata](https://csv2geo.com) . It comes with free and paid option
For API I would recommend mapbox  . It also come with free and paid option.
Another api is mapquest https://www.mapbox.com/geocoding/
Both API are easy to connect and use and javascript will not break.